# Internal Server Error in AltairChart with pandas DataFrame - Shapelets-Platform

Tags: python, function, time-series

I am trying to create a Dataapp on Shapelets Platform using the AltairChart and DataApp modules from the shapelets.apps library. However, when I run my code, I get an Internal Server Error with a Runtime error executing full_bar message.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
from shapelets.apps import AltairChart, DataApp
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

# import the full data csv file
papa_person = pd.read_csv('/root/Papa_johns_last/papa_person1.csv')
papa_person_group = papa_person.groupby("postalCode").mean()

one = papa_person_group.iloc[:,84+10:]
two = papa_person_group.iloc[:,41+10:44+10]
population = papa_person_group.iloc[:,7+10:12+10]
language = papa_person_group.iloc[:,12+10:17+10]
married = papa_person_group.iloc[:,17+10:22+10]
male_female = papa_person_group.iloc[:,4+10:6+10]
household = papa_person_group.iloc[:,22+10:29+10]
income = papa_person_group.iloc[:,29+10:41+10]
education = two.join(one)
employment = papa_person_group.iloc[:,45+10:66+10]
employment_group = papa_person_group.iloc[:,66+10:69+10]
age = papa_person_group.iloc[:,69+10:84+10]
leftover = papa_person_group.iloc[:,0+10:4+10]

cat={"Population":population, "Language":language, "Married":married, "Male Female":male_female, "Household":household, "Income":income, "Education":education, "Employement":employment, "Employement Group":employment_group, "Age":age, "Leftover":leftover}

app = DataApp(name= "Data")

def full_bar(cat: dict, selector_cat: str) -> AltairChart:
    cat = cat[selector_cat]
    melted_cat = pd.melt(cat.reset_index(), id_vars=['postalCode'], var_name='Feature', value_name='Count')

    # create stacked bar chart
    chart = alt.Chart(melted_cat).mark_bar().encode(
        x='postalCode:N',
        y='Count:Q',
        color='Feature:N',
        tooltip=['postalCode:N', 'Feature:N', 'Count:Q']
    ).properties(width=600, height=400, title='Bar Chart by Zipcode and Feature').interactive()

    return chart

# create the selector for the postalCodes
selector = app.selector(title="Select the Postal Code", options=['33122','33125','33126','33127','33128','33129','33130','33131','33132','33133','33134','33135','33136','33137','33138','33139','33140','33141','33142','33143','33144','33145','33146','33147','33148','33149','33150','33151','33152','33153','33155','33156','33157','33161','33162','33165','33166','33167','33168','33169','33170','33172','33173','33174','33175','33176','33177','33178','33179','33180','33181','33182','33183','33184','33185','33186','33187','33188','33189','33190','33193','33194'])
selector_cat = app.selector(title="Select the Categorie", options=['Income', 'Language', 'Population', 'Married', 'Education', 'Male Female', 'Employment', 'Employement Group', 'Age', 'Household', 'Leftover'])


image_full_bar = app.altair_chart()
image_full_bar.bind(full_bar, cat, selector_cat)

app.place(selector_cat)
app.place(image_full_bar)

app.register()
```

I am trying to show you my data, but it has more than 98 features, and it is pretty big

I tried to create a selector to trigger the image depending on the type of section, and everything is working without using Shapelets.

I am not sure what is causing the error. Can someone help me to understand what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, the issue here is that in your function you are trying to pass the return of the function into a chart, you should try to pass it as the Altair chart

try to replace this in your function

```
app.altair_chart(chart=chart)
```

you can look at your documentation https://shapelets.io/doc/ https://github.com/shapelets/shapelets-demo